# Counter Loops in Transition Systems - Z3

Tags: z3, transition-systems

I use the PDR engine of Z3 to prove invariants in transition systems.
When a transition system includes a counter loop which has to be passed to reach a specific state the performance is slow.

In the following source code you see an example of a transition system containing 3 states and 3 transitions implemented with the Transition System Python Class on the [Z3 Fixedpoint Homepage](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial/fixedpoints). In the last line there is a query to reach state L2 beginning from state L0. Therefore transition t2 has to be passed y times.

If I initialize y==10 the answer is computed fast. But with initialization y==1000 the performance is slow.

```
L0 = L.L0 
L1 = L.L1
L2 = L.L2
y=Int('y')
i = Int('i')
state  = Const('state', L)

t1 = { "guard" : state == L0,
   "effect" : [ L1, i ] }
t2 = { "guard" : And(state == L1),
   "effect" : [ L1, i+1 ] }
t3 = { "guard" : And(state == L1,i>y),
   "effect" : [ L2, i]}

ptr = TransitionSystem( And(state == L0, i == 0, y==10),[t1, t2, t3],[state, i])
ptr.query(state==L2)
```

Is there a possibility to compute the path from L0 to L2 in other way with Z3 achieving better performance ?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no faster approach in Z3 for your example. 
Z3's implementation spends roughly quadratic overhead in the 
depth of the counter-example loop as it attempts to push 
(the same) properties across the depth of the unfolding.

Generally speaking, Z3's PDR engine is not too well 
suited for planning problems. It is somewhat better when 
establishing that no traces exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you see a chance, that I can optimize the PDR engine to get it faster for such problems, e.g. by merging same properties at unfolding ?

Comment: ...or e.g. consider the transition system structure or state transitions separately at unfolding